# How to sort and array of dictionary based on key count

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Sorting an array of dictionary:

```
userDataArray: (
        {
        UUID = "A3BE3995-0B5B-A4EC-6A75-EEE7E94E20D1";
        readings =         (
                        {
                name = Blank;
                rssi = "-50";
                state = 0;
            },
                        (
                                {
                    name = Blank;
                    rssi = "-36";
                    state = 0;
                }
            )
        );
    },
        {
        UUID = "D6CAC8E3-D984-F68A-4688-2965778AB7D6";
        readings =         (
                        {
                name = "Blood Pressure";
                rssi = "-50";
                state = 0;
            },
                        (
                                {
                    name = "Blood Pressure";
                    rssi = "-45";
                    state = 0;
                }
            ),
                        (
                                {
                    name = "Blood Pressure";
                    rssi = "-43";
                    state = 0;
                }
            )
        );
    }
)
```

I want to sort this array based on the readings array count on every dictionary.

```
NSArray *sortedArr = [userDataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"SELF.readings.count" ascending:YES]]];
```

Will this do the trick?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work?

Comment: You can use only available `key` in dictionary for `sortDescriptor`, you can only use 'name', 'rssi', or 'state' only for sorting. according to your requirement you need to write custom logic.